# Ruby #{} inserts linebreaks

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have this string in Ruby with two variables:

```
INSERT INTO nodes (node, author) VALUES (#{line}, #{author})
```

However Ruby throws a line break after the `#{line}` i.e.

```
...... VALUES(xxxxxxx
, asdds)
```

Yes I know injection vulnerabilities and whatnot but this is just something I run on my dev machine with good data. I would not do this live.

Comment: Always escape such values, it's just a call to [`Mysql2::Client#escape`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.3.16/Mysql2/Client#escape-instance_method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `line` and `author` have leading/trailing whitespace. Try:

```
"... VALUES (#{line.strip}, #{author.strip})"
```

Comment: yep that's it, odd since i get the node from a database table where it is definitely stored without whitespace. Thanks anyways!!!!